Render Settings for an earth
I am new to Blender and created an earth and wanted to render it now but it says it will take up to 20hours and more!
It is an animation with 400 Frames and I have a gaming pc, so it shouldn't be such a problem. Yesterday I rendert an Iglo with some aurora lights (600 Frames) and it was onyl 2h.
The earth animation is for a university project in a planetarium which has a 2k (2160x2160) resolution.
Can anybody tell me what I can optimize in the render settings? Already watched so many videos but I am not sure what is right for my render :(
Thanks!
The earth:

Settings:
Sampling:

Light Paths:

Subdev & Simplify:

Film:

Performance:

Format:


Your Device > GPU Compute is greyed out, which means it will render with the CPU. This can take ages... go to Edit > Preferences > System and check your GPU under OptiX if available for your card or else CUDA. Oh and under Performance > Memory the Tile Size is set to 2048 pixels, your image is slightly larger with 2160 pixels, so it will be rendered in 4 tiles. Maybe try to disable tiling and render a single image to see if it is quicker than 4 tiles (if you are back to rendering with GPU Compute).

Omg thank you sooo much! I think turning on the GPU and render with bothsaved me like 24 h haha. Thanks again!
